# How to display woocommerce PRICE on product's BODY text - using SHORTCODE?

Tags: woocommerce, shortcode

I'm writing some details of each prodcuts (short/long description) on woocommerce.

i'd like to insert a SHORTCODE inside the description that shows the current PRICE (sale / regular).
it should look something like that on the backend:

"Buy it now, for only [wc_price] $"

is there any shortcode i can use for that?

Answer (score 1):

This is one the most simple snippet that does what you want without the need of inputting the id manually:

```
function my_shortcode_product_price() {
    $html = '';

    global $product;

    $price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_price() ) );

    $args = array(
            'ex_tax_label'       => false,
            'currency'           => 'USD',
            'decimal_separator'  => '.',
            'thousand_separator' => ' ',
            'decimals'           => 2,
            'price_format'       => '%2$s&nbsp;%1$s',
        );

    $html = "<span>" . wc_price( $price, $args ) . "</span>";

    return $html;
 }
 add_shortcode( 'product_price', 'my_shortcode_product_price' );
```

The above code goes in the `functions.php` file of your active theme. After that you can use the shortcode like this:

```
[product_price]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You Go: add this code in your function.php

```
    function short_code_woo_comm_desc( $atts ) {
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'id' => null
), $atts, 'tag_for_short_code_price' );

if ( empty( $atts[ 'id' ] ) ) {
    return '';
}

$product = wc_get_product( $atts['id'] );

if ( ! $product ) {
    return '';
}

       return $product->get_price_html();
    }

    add_shortcode( 'tag_for_short_code_price', 'short_code_woo_comm_desc' );
```

Use:

```
    [tag_for_short_code_price id="101"]
```

Comment: thank you so much.
do i have to use product id? is there anyway that'll auto-determine product id on current product?